# jQuery parse error in getJSON

Tags: jquery, getjson

While searching for a product using ProductWiki APIs, I am running into JSON parse errors. Could you let me know if I am missing something or is the data that is returned not properly formatted?

Here is the JavaScript code I am using

```
var searchUrl = "http://api.productwiki.com/connect/api.aspx?" +
            "&op=search" +
            "&key=" + API_KEY_PRODUCT_WIKI +
            "&q=" + nugget +
            "&format=json" +
            "&jsoncallback=?";

 $.getJSON(searchUrl, function (data) { alert("Got data"); });
```

On executing the code, I am getting the following data back from productwiki

```
{"__type":"ProductWiki.DataStructures.API.Schema.pw_api_results, ProductWiki.DataStructures, Version=1.0.4622.22636, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","message":null,"num_results":2,"products":[{"__type":"ProductWiki.DataStructures.API.Schema.product, ProductWiki.DataStructures, Version=1.0.4622.22636, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","url":"http://www.productwiki.com/microsoft-surface/","id":15113,"title":"Microsoft Surface","description":null,"proscore":"41","number_of_reviews":"13","category":"Computers","key_features":[],"images":[{"__type":"ProductWiki.DataStructures.API.Schema.image, ProductWiki.DataStructures, Version=1.0.4622.22636, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","title":"Microsoft Surface","rawimage":"http://images.productwiki.com/upload/images/microsoft_surface.jpg","largeimage":"http://images.productwiki.com/upload/images/microsoft_surface-400-400.jpg","mediumimage":"http://images.productwiki.com/upload/images/microsoft_surface-100-100.jpg","smallimage":"http://images.productwiki.com/upload/images/microsoft_surface-60-60.jpg"}],"community_review":null,"reviews":null,"tags":null,"competitors":null,"related":null,"skus":null},{"__type":"ProductWiki.DataStructures.API.Schema.product, ProductWiki.DataStructures, Version=1.0.4622.22636, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","url":"http://www.productwiki.com/menotek-flexible-bluetooth-waterproof-mini-keyboard/","id":59084,"title":"Menotek Flexible Bluetooth Waterproof Mini Keyboard","description":null,"proscore":"62","number_of_reviews":"1","category":"Keyboards","key_features":[],"images":[{"__type":"ProductWiki.DataStructures.API.Schema.image, ProductWiki.DataStructures, Version=1.0.4622.22636, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","title":"Menotek Flexible Bluetooth Waterproof Mini Keyboard","rawimage":"http://images.productwiki.com/upload/images/menotek_flexible_bluetooth_waterproof_mini_keyboard.jpg","largeimage":"http://images.productwiki.com/upload/images/menotek_flexible_bluetooth_waterproof_mini_keyboard-400-400.jpg","mediumimage":"http://images.productwiki.com/upload/images/menotek_flexible_bluetooth_waterproof_mini_keyboard-100-100.jpg","smallimage":"http://images.productwiki.com/upload/images/menotek_flexible_bluetooth_waterproof_mini_keyboard-60-60.jpg"}],"community_review":null,"reviews":null,"tags":null,"competitors":null,"related":null,"skus":null}]}
```

but it also throws the jquery error

```
JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 10 in http://api.productwiki.com/connect/api.aspx?&op=search&key=***&q=microsoftsurface&format=json&jsoncallback=jQuery18308245886188083906_1356907329390&_=1356907329577

SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
```

I tried validating the response from productwiki at [JSON Formatter & validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and did not find any issues. Wondering if I am missing something or is the data from product wiki not in the right format?

Comment: jQuery expects JSONP but the response is JSON. JSON by itself is not valid JavaScript, hence you get the error. The server has to support JSONP, so maybe try `format=jsonp` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think productwiki does not support jsonp. I ended up accessing their API from server side